# Referencing various dataframes from within a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to use various data frames within a single for loop, ie:

```
#after loading the 5 data frames
for(i in 1:5){
    dframe <- dataframe[i]
    print(sprintf("This is data frame %s", dframe)
}
```

However this only passes the variable name and not the data frame itself. Thanks.

Comment: print.data.frame(dframe)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the data use the [`get`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/get.html) function.

```
dframe <- get(dataframe[i])
```